# How do you overwrite the left/right arrow images (and images in general) in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the standard Bootstrap carousel, but I want to overwrite the left/right arrows with my own images, as well as the indicators at the bottom:

[image]

I can't find anywhere where these are being included, or what source they're taken from. Where/how do I overwrite these? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start by inspecting the element and checking in the browser dev window the styles applied to it. There you'll find a reference to the image being loaded and where it sits in the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Images aren't used for this part of the Bootstrap carousel, it is a icon font

Comment: @MelanciaUK I did this, and there's no reference to images anywhere, just a style that's being applied

Comment: @rwacarter How do you override an icon font with a custom image? Is that even possible? Or do you just have to apply your own style to the icon font? I've never done this before. I was able to replace the left/right arrows with my own images, but as for the bottom dot indicators, I don't know how to go about changing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to generate your own icon font. There's a detailed tutorial here: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-svg-icons/

Basically, you need all your images to be svgs, and then you use a service like https://icomoon.io/ to generate the font.

Once you have your font, you use @font-face to embed it into your project, and you need to overwrite the code so it uses your font, and the character.

For example, you'd need to add his to your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?n2igc9');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefixn2igc9') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?n2igc9') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?n2igc9') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?n2igc9#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.carousel .glyphicon { font-family: 'icomoon'; }
```

The last line of code will change all the icons in the carousel to use the font you generated in icomoon,

And to change the individual icons (in this case, the icon of the right arrow):

```
.carousel .glyphicon-chevron-right:before { content: "\e604"; }
```

When you download from icomoon, it will come with a demo with the code showing all the characters.

Comment: Is there away you can overwrite, or just change the style of the existing icon-fonts or is that impossible?

Comment: I'll change my answer to be more specific.